# Formatting VBA - adding spaces between sections

Tags: vba, excel, format, spaces

I have this code which works well that loops through a folder, opens a file, prints the name of the file to Column 1 of my Masterfile(*the file with the code and where all of my final information will go*), prints 2 columns (*of varying length since I use End(xlUp) to get all of the info present in the column*) from the file into columns 2 and 3, and prints the cell J1 from the file to column 4 in the masterfile.

My problem: There is only one name of the file, one J1 cell, but multiple entries in columns 2 and 3. I need to space it out so the name and J1 are printed in the top of each new entry. I have attached photos to explain what I mean. Columns 2 and 3 should be listed next to their corresponding file names (preferable with an extra space between each new file).

(*I have color coded them only to show my meaning*)
Picture 1: How it currenlty looks (all info just dumped into each column)
Picture 2: How I want it to look (the file names spaced out so horizontally, all of the information corresponds to the same file)

The code to output this data is also below. Thank you very much for any help/guidance you can give me!

Picture 1:
[image: Picture1]
Picture 2:

### [image]

```
Option Explicit

Sub LoopThroughDirectory()

    Dim objFSO As Object
    Dim objFolder As Object
    Dim objFile As Object
    Dim MyFolder As String
    Dim StartSht As Worksheet, ws As Worksheet
    Dim WB As Workbook
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim LastRow As Integer, erow As Integer
    Dim Height As Integer

    'turn screen updating off - makes program faster
    'Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    'location of the folder in which the desired TDS files are
    MyFolder = "C:\Users\trembos\Documents\TDS\progress\"

    'Set StartSht = ActiveSheet
    Set StartSht = Workbooks("masterfile.xlsm").Sheets("Sheet1")

    'create an instance of the FileSystemObject
    Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    'get the folder object
    Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(MyFolder)
    i = 1

    'loop through directory file and print names
    For Each objFile In objFolder.Files
        If LCase(Right(objFile.Name, 3)) = "xls" Or LCase(Left(Right(objFile.Name, 4), 3)) = "xls" Then
            'print file name to Column 1
            Workbooks.Open fileName:=MyFolder & objFile.Name
            Set WB = ActiveWorkbook


            'print "HOLDER" column
            'Range("HOLDER").AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, CriteriaRange:=WB.Range(Rows.count, 6).End(xlUp).Row, CopyToRange:=StartSht.Range(Rows.count, 2).End(xlUp).Row, Unique:=False

            'WB.Range("F10:F25").Value = StartSht.Range("C2:C17").Value

'            For i = 1 To 20
'                ActiveSheet.Range("F10:F25") = StartSht("Sheet1").Range("C2:C17")
'            Next i

'            Range(Rows.count, 6).End(xlUp).Row.Copy
'            StartSht.Activate
'            Range(Rows.count, 2).End(xlUp).Row.Select
'            ActiveSheet.Paste
'
'            WB.Activate

            LastRow = Cells(Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
            Range(Cells(11, 6), Cells(LastRow, 6)).Copy
            StartSht.Activate
            Range("B" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).PasteSpecial
            WB.Activate

            LastRow = Cells(Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
            Range(Cells(11, 7), Cells(LastRow, 7)).Copy
            StartSht.Activate
            Range("C" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).PasteSpecial
            WB.Activate

            'print TOOLING DATA SHEET(TDS): values to Column 2
            With WB
                For Each ws In .Worksheets
                    StartSht.Cells(i + 1, 1) = objFile.Name
                    With ws
                        .Range("J1").Copy StartSht.Cells(i + 1, 4)
                    End With
                    i = i + 1
                'move to next file
                Next ws
                'close, do not save any changes to the opened files
                .Close SaveChanges:=False
            End With
        End If
    'move to next file
    Next objFile
    'turn screen updating back on
    'Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Option Explicit

Sub LoopThroughDirectory()

Dim objFSO As Object
Dim objFolder As Object
Dim objFile As Object
Dim MyFolder As String
Dim StartSht As Worksheet, ws As Worksheet
Dim WB As Workbook
Dim i As Integer
Dim LastRow As Integer, erow As Integer
Dim Height As Integer

'turn screen updating off - makes program faster
'Application.ScreenUpdating = False

'location of the folder in which the desired TDS files are
MyFolder = "C:\Users\trembos\Documents\TDS\progress\"

'Set StartSht = ActiveSheet
Set StartSht = Workbooks("masterfile.xlsm").Sheets("Sheet1")

'create an instance of the FileSystemObject
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
'get the folder object
Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(MyFolder)
i = 1

'loop through directory file and print names
For Each objFile In objFolder.Files
    If LCase(Right(objFile.Name, 3)) = "xls" Or LCase(Left(Right(objFile.Name, 4), 3)) = "xls" Then
        'print file name to Column 1
        Workbooks.Open fileName:=MyFolder & objFile.Name
        Set WB = ActiveWorkbook
        LastRow = Cells(Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        Range(Cells(11, 6), Cells(LastRow, 6)).Copy
        StartSht.Activate
    nextRow = Range("B" & Rows.count).End(xlUp) + 1
        Range("B" & nextRow).PasteSpecial
        WB.Activate

        LastRow = Cells(Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        Range(Cells(11, 7), Cells(LastRow, 7)).Copy
        StartSht.Activate
        Range("C" & nextRow).PasteSpecial
        WB.Activate

        'print TOOLING DATA SHEET(TDS): values to Column 2
        With WB
            For Each ws In .Worksheets
                StartSht.Cells(nextRow, 1) = objFile.Name
                With ws
                    .Range("J1").Copy StartSht.Cells(nextRow, 4)
                End With
                i = i + 1
            'move to next file
            Next ws
            'close, do not save any changes to the opened files
            .Close SaveChanges:=False
        End With
    End If
'move to next file
Next objFile
'turn screen updating back on
'Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

End Sub

Comment: Could you explain this a bit more please? It looks like you added `nextRow` into the code ... but it is not defined anywhere so I get back errors @Abe Gold

Comment: Dim it as Integer. The way you did it, you are using i as the row to put the file name. What I'm doing is setting the next available row to a variable and using that to paste all the info, including the file name. If you do it that way, you don't have to keep on doing Range("B" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Offset(1) the way you did it.

Comment: Okay. The next error says that the line `Range("B" & nextRow).PasteSpecial` is : Method 'Range' of object'_Global' failed meaning it is not an acceptable range. Would I not have to set what nextRow is equal to  as I did with LastRow in the line `LastRow = Cells(Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Row` ?

Comment: Also, not sure how to implement it but would an offset be faster or no? _such as `...(xlUp).offset(1,0).pastespecial`_

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `Range("B" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row + 2` as your first row for all of the columns, because it's the last row of all the data, +2 rows for one space.

Your paste statements should look something like this:

```
Dim lRow as Long
...
lRow = StartSht.Range("B" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row + 2
...
StartSht.Range("B" & lRow).PasteSpecial
...
StartSht.Range("C" & lRow).PasteSpecial
...
i = lRow
...
    StartSht.Cells(i, 1) = objFile.Name
    ...
    .Range("J1").Copy StartSht.Cells(i, 4)
    i = i + 1
```

**Addition**: Calculate `lRow' for each new file, as the first row changes after the last file was added to the data.

Also, it's a better practice to use the full reference. Instead of using `.Activate` use `StartSht.Range("C" & lRow).PasteSpecial`, and the same goes for `WB`. With WB also make sure the active sheet is the right one, the full reference `WB.Sheets([]).Range(...`.

Comment: Okay... it used to print out 5 file names in column 1, around 30 lines of info in columns 2 and 3 (the 5 files info piled together), and 5 cells in column 4. Now it's overwriting something.. because it prints one name 3 lines down, 1 of the files column 2 and 3 info, and only 1 cell name in column 4...

Comment: okay, I change that and it will still not work correctly. now some of the file names are printing multiple times and their corresponding tools arent in the correct order anymore. the five files names print, then there are  10 spaces and six files (one repeat) prints, then there are 19 spaces and two of the same files print... the fourth column and the first column do at least seem to line up though..

Comment: Do you know how I should fix that? @dePatinkin

Comment: You calculated lRow for WB instead of StartSht. Maybe you should take my suggestion of using the full reference instead of Active and then you'll be aware of what you're doing. You should also debug your code and see that you are getting the right lRow value